# What is the name for the fine line patterns on bank notes?

Tags: single-word-requests

Bank notes (and other certificates) typically have patterns of fine lines, for example the pattern behind the lion here, from the [Bank of England Museum](https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/museum/online-collections/banknotes/banknote-design):

[image]

**Do these patterns have a name?** What is the proper name for these patterns?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're looking for the term **Guilloché pattern**:

> Guilloché patterns are spirograph-like curves that frame a curve within an inner and outer envelope curve. They are used on banknotes, securities, and passports worldwide for added security against counterfeiting. — [Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GuillochePattern.html)

More examples at [Math Games](https://www.mathpuzzle.com/MAA/13-Guilloche%20Patterns/mathgames_02_09_04.html).

More informally, they're known as *Spirograph patterns*. A Spirograph is a popular toy so this is the most well-known name.

---

Barmar asked a follow up question on Money SE about how this works: [How does Guilloché pattern inhibit counterfeiting?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/155415/how-does-guilloch%C3%A9-pattern-inhibit-counterfeiting)